# Generate numbers at random time intervals with rx

Tags: system.reactive

How can I generate a list of number with Rx.Net, like 0-100, where each number is generated at a random time?

edit:

seems like this works

```
    public void NonBlocking_event_driven()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var ob = Observable.Create<int>(
        observer =>
        {
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => observer.OnNext(random.Next(0, 3));
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
            timer.Start();
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
        var subscription = ob.Subscribe(UserAction);
        Console.ReadLine();
        subscription.Dispose();
    }
    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        timer.Interval = random.Next(1, 10)*1000;
        Console.WriteLine(e.SignalTime);
    }
```

Comment: Be more specific. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an operator for that, you can use Generate:

```
var source = Observable.Generate(
  0,
  x => x < 100,
  x => x + 1,
  _ => random.Next(0, 3),
  _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(random.Next(1, 10)* 1000));

source.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: For those who have issues with this blocking for an infinite series, use the `IScheduler` parameter.