# Create Observable for Streaming Class in Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.reactive

How do I create an Observable for a class?
Eg here is class for continuous sales

```
public class Product
{
     public int ProductId {get;set;}
     public string ProductDescription {get;set;}
     public float Sales{get;set;}
}
```

How to create Observable? Say they are coming into a `List<Product>` with Add(), products keep getting added representing transactions.

Anytime, a product is added anywhere in Console program, the subscriber will observe it.

```
var productSample1 = new Product { ProductId = 1, ProductDescription = "Furniture" };
var productSample2 = new Product { ProductId = 2, ProductDescription = "Book" };
var productSample3 = new Product { ProductId = 3, ProductDescription = "car" };

var productlist = new List<Product>();
productlist.Add(productSample1);
....
productlist.Add(productSample2);
...
productlist.Add(productSample3);
```

Maybe something like this,

```
var products = Observable.FromEventPattern < EventHandler<Product>, Product>();
```

Trying to read resources below, trying to add on ,

[Generate numbers at random time intervals with rx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733906/generate-numbers-at-random-time-intervals-with-rx)

[Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#CreationOfObservables)

Comment: what is the lifetime of your generator (how Products are incoming)? It's not that easy to answer. It could be a cold/hot observable, Observable.FromEventPattern/ Observable.Create/ ...

Comment: hi @ntohl say 20 products a minute, it can be a hot observable

Comment: How does your generation look like? Where is the code, where the `new Product` would be? Or that is what you like to delegate to Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1):

```
var list = new ObservableCollection<int>();
using (var o = Observable
    .FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(h => list.CollectionChanged += h, h => list.CollectionChanged -= h)
    .Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine($"{e.EventArgs.Action} {e.EventArgs.NewItems[0]}")))
{
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(10);
}

// Add 1
// Add 10
```

Or turn it around and add from a subscription:

```
var list = new List<int>();
var subject = new Subject<int>();
using (var o = subject.Subscribe(i => list.Add(i)))
{
    subject.OnNext(1);
    subject.OnNext(10);
}

foreach (var i in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

// 1
// 10
```

Comment: Thanks, and anytime I run the statement, list.Add(productSample3), or, list.Add(productSample4), or list.Add(productSample5), in another totally  separate statements, it will, automatically read into Observable?

Comment: also, another question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296396/entity-framework-convert-changetracker-to-observable-with-reactive-stream?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @earlwatkins85, what do you mean by "automatically read into Observable"?

Comment: I described more in question, also; why did we get rid of Product and replace with int, trying to specify answer to question for custom class, thanks

Comment: The item type doesn't matter. This answer is valid for any item type and has the corresponding console output in the comments.